# Why doesn't this template signature work as a string-literal using quotes?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, user-defined-literals

C++11 permits user-defined template string-literal operators, with the following template signature ([taken from CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal); the return type does not need to be `double`):

```
template <char...> double operator "" _x();
```

However, it appears that this only works in the numeric form, not the quoted form:

```
template <char... chs>
std::string operator ""_r()
{
    // ... construct some sort of string and return it
}

// ... 

auto my_str = "abc"_r;  // ERROR (compiler messages copied below)
auto my_num = 123_r;    // NO ERROR
```

Neither GCC (5.1) nor Clang (3.7) give a useful error message. GCC says:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘operator""_r()’
// printed source elided
note: candidate: template<char ...chs> std::__cxx11::string operator""_r()
// printed source elided
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
// ERROR OUTPUT ENDS HERE
// (nothing is printed here, despite the ':' in the previous line)
```

Clang simply says:

```
error: no matching literal operator for call to 'operator "" _r' with arguments of types 'const char *' and 'unsigned long', and no matching literal operator template
```

So why does template argument deduction fail? Why does the literal operator template not match?

And, in general, is it possible to fix the usage so that `template <char...>` literal-operators can be used with non-numeric strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare user-defined string literals that accepts a variadic char pack. This may change in the future, but as of now, that's all there is to it.

From the same cppreference:

> For user-defined string literals, the user-defined literal expression
>   is treated as a function call `operator "" X (str, len)`, where str is
>   the literal without *ud-suffix* and len is its length excluding the
>   terminating null character

Comment: Ah, I see -- integer literals and floating-point literals are explicitly said to be treated as a function call `operator "" X<'c1', 'c2', 'c3'..., 'ck'>()` if the other possible literal operators aren't available. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Gcc has **extension** to allow

```
template <typename Char, Char...Cs>
std::string operator ""_r()
{
    // ... construct some sort of string and return it
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/227730f6406af9dc)

Comment: Since I did try this with GCC 5, I guess this must be new in GCC 6?

Comment: According to [that](https://godbolt.org/g/036ejP), since gcc 4.9 (but with c++14).

Comment: Oh, right, I used `<char...>` instead of `<typename Char, Char...>`.